# How do I change the color of my DIV when checkbox is checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change the color of the DIV when a checkbox is checked. I want to do this in jQuery. I have tried this :

```
 if($('#checkboxTest').is(':checked'))
    {
        $('.alertWrapper').css('background-color', 'blue');
    }
```

But it is not working.. any help?

Comment: Your code seems alright, you have to show us the context of js and html you have

Comment: What your probably looking for is called [Events](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/). If not, post your whole code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `change` event :

```
$('#checkboxTest').change(function() {
   var c = this.checked ? 'blue' : 'transparent';
   $('.alertWrapper').css('background-color', c);
});
```

**[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b9ts4/)**

Answer (score 2):

You need to use **[.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/)** event to keep track of the state of your checkbox:

```
$('#checkboxTest').change(function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
    {
        $('.alertWrapper').css('background-color', 'blue');
    } else {
        // Your code here will fired when the checkbox is unchecked
    }
}).change(); // <-- Trigger the change event on page load
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following (with click event):

```
$('#checkboxTest').click (function ()
{
 var thisCheck = $(this);
 if (thischeck.is (':checked'))
 {
  // your stuff
 }
});
```